# dimple.js or d3.js - Draw chart's legend at bottom of svg element

Tags: d3.js, visualization, rickshaw, dimple.js

I'm trying to figure out how to get my legend to appear at the bottom of a chart but having no luck.
In the code below, since my chart has a height of 600, i figure i could simply add an offset of 600 for the Y coordinate and that would do the trick.  Does not work however.

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chart", 800, 600);
...
chart.addLegend(0, 600 + 40, 200, 10, "left");
```

Anyone know how to solve this either with dimple.js or d3.js?  It would also be great if i did not have to hard code these values and instead could do something like this:

```
chart.addLegend(0, d3.select("#chart").height + 40, 200, 10, "left");
```

here is the documentation for addLegend for dimple.js:
https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#addLegend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be Ok.

Please check js fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/ch2187dd/)

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 540);
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
myChart.setBounds(90, 35, 480, 325)
myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["date"]);
myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", "close");
myChart.addSeries("Price Tier", dimple.plot.bubble);
myChart.addLegend(90, 480, 330, 20, "left");
myChart.draw();
```

Comment: Thank you. i think i mas missing the setBounds.  i guess the svg dimension is the overall 'canvas' area and the setBounds methods confines the chart to an area within the svg canvas, leaving room to draw other shapes/elements?